# LWJGL 3.1.6 OpenGL 4.1 crash on macOS High Sierra

Tags: opengl, crash, lwjgl, macos-high-sierra, forward-compatibility

I have a slightly modified version of the [sample code](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) found on the main LWJGL page. It works but it uses legacy OpenGL version `2.1`. If I attempt to use the forward-compatible context described in [GLFW doc](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context), the version used is `4.1` (no matter what major/minor I hint), the window is created, but **it crashes** on the first call to `glPushMatrix()`.

Forward compatibility enabled like so:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Some info I print in the console:

```
LWJGL 3.1.6 build 14
OS name Mac OS X
OS version 10.13.4
OpenGL version 4.1 ATI-1.66.31
```

Logging:

```
[LWJGL] A function that is not available in the current context was called.
Problematic frame:
C  [liblwjgl.dylib+0x1c494]
```

From here I don't know what to look for. Should this code be working? Or am I missing some ceremony? Many resources are outdated, making it harder to figure things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glPushMatrix` is a function for not Core Profile context, but for OpenGL < 3.2.

If you want to use it (and other pre-core features) you need a **Compatibility** context, not a *Forward compatible* one, not a *Core profile* either.

The `GLFW` hints should be like these, without asking for a Core Profile.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

Likely the driver will give the highest available version, but with all of old features too.

Comment: Doing so crashes earlier, on `glfwCreateWindow` with `GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE error` - :NSGL: The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above." (I've tried 3.2 or 4.1). Looks like I'm keep your distinction btwn core, compatibility and forward compatibility in mind and do some research.

Comment: Try without asking for a context version, setting GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE as the only hint. What version do you get so?

Comment: Mmm... [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/enumerations/1436146-opengl_profiles) seems to exclude the posibility of having pre-core and core features at once.

Comment: "Context profiles are only defined for OpenGL version 3.2 and above" on `nglfwCreateWindow()`. Seems to be a dead-end. Either let it run with 2.1, or I ought to do it differently. The thing is that the code samples I've found (incl. in the official doc) for LWJGL only do it that way.