# LWJGL3 game crash on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am currently creating a game using LWJGL 3 for Java 11. Every time I try to launch it on MacOs, it crashes. I have deduced that the error is caused by GLFW and is related to these lines of code:

```
glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

I already tried [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802367/lwjgl-3-1-6-opengl-4-1-crash-on-macos-high-sierra) but it doesn't work either.

```
glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

[That's the error log](https://pastebin.com/xXNdhEDt)

I don't know how to avoid the game crash. I already searched for other answers on StackOverflow but I couldn't find anything helpful.
[Link to the repository](https://bitbucket.org/fcdevgit/cubicworldsimulatortest/)

Comment: Use -XstartOnFirstThread JVM argument to launch game on Mac OS platform.